# Unable to send URL

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL to send a URL. It's not sending an URL which contains PHP variables although is working perfectly on a defined URL (not incuding any PHP variable).

**For example: This link is not working because of PHP variables :**

```
$url = "http://abc/create/name/{$firstname} {$lastname}/email/{$email}/password/{$password1}?level={$level}&session=Dec";

$request = curl_init($url);
$response = curl_exec($request);
var_dump($response);
```

**This works fine: Contains static values**

```
$url = "http://abc/create/name/any one/email/anyone@gmail.com/password/12345?level=1&session=Dec";

$request = curl_init($url);
$response = curl_exec($request);
var_dump($response);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any leads?

**Note: The URL is perfectly echoed, No error in `echo $url`**

Comment: Did we forget to set the **$** to lastname and email? ;)

Comment: no no, its my typo error here , Corrected!

Comment: Have you tried doing `echo $url` to make sure the variables are set the way you expect them to be?

Comment: try prefixing forward slash before special chars in the url string. i.e. \{\$ etc

Comment: @BA_Webimax yes URL is set :) but i dont know why its not sending it :(

Comment: Did you actually set the variables lastname and email?

Answer (score 0):

please putt like this and it will work

`$url = 'http://abc/create/name/{'.$firstname.'}{'.$lastname.'}/email/{'.$email.'}/password/{'.$password1.'}?level={'.$level.'}&session=Dec"';`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution :)

I am giving a space between in my `{$firstname} {$lastname}`thats why its not sending the URL.
So i just concatenate my firstname and lastname in a single variable and it works like a charm.

```
$fullname = $get_user_firstname.$get_user_lastname;
$fullname = urlencode($fullname);

$url = "http://abc/create/name/{$fullname}/email/{$email}/password/{$password1}?level={$level}&session=Dec";
```

Hope anyone with similar issue can get help from my this answer that's why i posted it. cheers!